# EmberJS not passing my dynamic route segment to the api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an API (I am writing in ASP.Net Web API) that has an end point which returns all of the counties in a state.

My route should look like this: http://localhost:4200/counties/CA or http://localhost:4200/counties/NY

My API is working fine.

However, I am getting: `Error while processing route: counties Ember Data Request GET http://localhost:50523/api/counties returned a 404`

My router mapping is:

```
// router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('states');
  this.route('counties', {path : 'counties/:state'});
});
```

I also tried `'counties/:fips'` - fips is the primaryKey designated in the serializer. And  `'counties/:county_id'` and  `'counties/:state_id'` for the hell of it.

```
// routes/counties.js is:
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('county', {state: params.state});
  }
});

// models/county.js:
export default DS.Model.extend({
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  countyName: DS.attr('string'),
  fips: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Note that the states route and API are working just dandy.

Edit: Based on comments @LUX I realized that I needed to wire things up a bit more before testing the route. So I modified my states template to include a link for each state listed like so:

```
// templates/companies
{{#each model as |state|}}
<p>{{#link-to "counties" state.state}}{{state.state}} - {{state.stateName}}/link-to}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

I also fixed my model hook (see above)

Now I get the right URL in the status bar of the browser when hovering over the link, but I still get the exact same error. I went over all of the code again, comparing to two other sample projects I have been examining, and I am just not seeing the problem.

Edit:

Here is my adapter:

```
// adapters/application.js
import WebApiAdapter from 'ember-web-api/adapters/web-api';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default WebApiAdapter.extend({
  host: config.host,
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it? The router is for the ember routes, and so the URL in the browser. Not the URLs of your API.
The dynamic segment is passed to your `model` hook:

```
model(params) {
  console.log(params.state);
}
```

Also `findAll` is to fetch *all* records for a given type. So you should use `query`:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.query('county', { state: params.state });
}
```

Now you have the state available in the adapter and you can make the proper request.

Comment: That got me closer, thanks. I am still missing something. See edits.

Comment: You have to return the right URL from your adapter. What is your adapter?

Comment: I added my adapter code to my question. Would I need a different adapter than the default application one? The states route is working fine so I assume the adapter is all good.